# Facebook app wont let me submit it to directory?

Tags: facebook

I just finished up building my facebook app and I'm trying to submit it to the facebook app directory, when I click on submit though the page just hangs and it appears to try and be loading the page but nothing ever happens. I've tried this on IE and Firefox.

Is there a list of requirements on what an app needs before you can submit it?

Thanks

I have 115 Monthly Active Users for my app, but when I click on the submit button it just doesn't do anything. My mouse turns into a loading icon, but it never actually loads anything.

Comment: You need to have at least 5 total users or 10 monthly active users before you can submit your application

Comment: It could just be a site-wide issue on Facebook.com. Try looking on [Facebook's BugZilla](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net) to see if someone's already reported it or maybe report it as an issue yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your app must :

a) be finished and not under construction

b) have at least 5 total users or 10 monthly active users

My app has completed a) but I don't understand what "total users / monthly active users" are.

Comment: Please don't add links to your own facebook apps, it is generally considered *spam*, unless it is integral to the answer (read the FAQ, section 'May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?').

Comment: I have 115 Monthly Active Users for my app, but when I click on the submit button it just doesn't do anything. My mouse turns into a loading icon, but it never actually loads anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I don't know why but today was the day!

I clicked the link and it worked..

I have
Monthly Active Users
15

People Who Like This
13

Total Users
31

Comment: (i couldn't write a comment so i posted the answer)